# RoR - howto convert some HTML-elements with css to Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, forms

I have old HTML code with html and css..

```
<form action="login" method="post"> 
<div class="field">
   <label for="username">Username</label>
   <input type="text" class="text" id="username" name="username" value="just click login !"/>
</div>
<span class="fright">
<button class="button" type="submit"><strong>Log In</strong></button>
</span>
</div>
```

How can i convert this code to decent rails code?
I came up with this, but it ain't right :-( :

```
<% form_for :user, @user,  :url => { :action => "login" } do |f| %>
<% div_for f, :class => "field text" do  %>
        <%= f.text_field :username %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "field text" %>
    <% end %>
    <span class="fright">
    <%= submit_tag '<strong>Inloggen</strong>', :class => "button",:disable_with => 'verwerken...' %></span>
<% end %>
```

I'm having problems with the

```
 <strong>Inloggen</strong>
```

And with the

```
<% div_for f, :class => "field text" do  %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submit_tag` generates the text as the value attribute of the `input` tag.

```
submit_tag "Edit this article"
# => <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Edit this article" />
```

So adding `strong` to that text is not gonna work, and it generates a `<input>` and it appears you want a `<button>`.  So just use html here as well.

```
<button class="button" type="submit"><strong>Log In</strong></button>
```

Since you dont need to alter this based on any variables, you don't need to render it with ruby.

---

And you don't need `div_for` based on your target HTML.  Simply use .  No reason to make your template render that with ruby.

---

Lesson here is don't try too hard.  Sometimes plain HTML is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<% form_for :user, @user,  :url => { :action => "login" } do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "field text" %>
  </div>
  <span class="fright">
    <%= submit_tag 'Inloggen', :class => "button strong",:disable_with => 'verwerken...' %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

I moved `<strong>` from submit_tag description to class, because I'm not sure if submit tag will accept it. So you need to define .strong class in your css.

Comment: It's not working, sorry.
I tried it and it's the same effect as my previous used code

Comment: There are no errors.
Only the lay-out isn't correct.

I need:
- The text from the button in <strong></strong>, because of css button design. Below is my css from <strong>
.button strong {
 background:url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat 100% -150px;
 display:block;
 height:30px;
 line-height:28px;
 padding-right:10px;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
so changing the strong class in css won't work for my layout.

-Also, the textboxes class = "field text", it's not the elements who are encapsulated with this class. It is the design of the form-elements.

Comment: Ok, I got your point now. As I googled around it seams that Rails doesn't provide any helpers to create `<button>`, so you can write your own or just don't write it in RoR - leave it as it was in html. It won't be bad to do so :)

Comment: Don't know how to write it, so i'll leave it in html.
Thank you, your comment is the answer, so i'll accept above ;)

Thanks!